# For loop with step

Tags: python, reflection, for-loop, operators

I have created a python script that can loop over a range of values based on a specified step function.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def mul(value, step): return value * step
def inc(value, step): return value + step
def step_range(start, end, step, func):
    while start <= end:
        yield start
        start = func(start, step)

def main():
    for x in step_range(1, 64, 2, mul): 
        print '%d, '%(x),
    print
    for x in step_range(0, 64, 8, inc): 
        print '%d, '%(x),

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
$ python test.py
1,  2,  4,  8,  16,  32,  64,
0,  8,  16,  24,  32,  40,  48,  56,  64,
```

Is there anyway I can get rid of the helper functions so that the user can do something like this?

```
for x in step_range(1, 64, *2): 
    ...

def step_range(start, end, step):
    while start <= end:
        yield start
        start = start ?step?
```

The `?` marks where I am stumped... I looked into the [`operator`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) module but I would have to know both parameters for the `mul(a, b)` and `add(a, b)` functions.

Comment: If your solution seems right for your use case, and generally applicable to someone who might come here in the future, you should post it as an answer and accept your own answer.

Comment: I know that the lambda was probably the best answer, but it may add too much complexity to my problem especially with the condition which I considered in my answer below. Thanks!

Comment: While we're at it, one more way to solve your problem: transform an iterator you know how to build into the one you actually want with a generator expression. And then you _don't_ need functions. But you need completely different expressions, of course. For example: `(1 << i for i in itertools.count())` gives you the infinite iterator `1, 2, 4, 8, ...`. Then you can filter it further from there (although really, I'd probably use `takewhile`, which gets you right back to needing a function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imported `operator` and I believe I came up with a good solution:

I kept my original `step_range()` function intact and I got rid of the helpers. I also added the ability to modify the condition in the case of decrementing values.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import operator

def step_range(start, end, step, step_func, compare_func):
    while compare_func(start, end):
        yield start
        start = step_func(start, step)

def main():
    print [x for x in step_range(1, 64, 2, operator.mul, operator.le)]
    print [x for x in step_range(64, 0, 2, operator.div, operator.gt)]
    print [x for x in step_range(0, 64, 8, operator.add, operator.le)]
    print [x for x in step_range(64, 0, 8, operator.sub, operator.ge)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
$ python test.py
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
[64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
[0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64]
[64, 56, 48, 40, 32, 24, 16, 8, 0]
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 4):

A clearer way of doing this would probably be

```
def step_range(start, end, func):
    while start <= end:
        yield start
        start = func(start)
```

Then for example, you could do

```
[a for a in step_range(1, 10, lambda x: x * 2)] # [1, 2, 4, 8]
```

That way you're not limited to just multiplication or addition. It's also much more Pythonic and clear when you're reading it.

Comment: Well, I really like the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to get rid of the function. A caller can't pass an expression to be evaluated, only a function to be called. (Plus, `*2` isn't even an expression, it's just a fragment of an expression…)

---

But Python comes with a lot of ways to build functions besides `def`. For example, there's `lambda`, and higher-order functions like `partial`:

```
>>> for x in step_range(1, 64, lambda x: x*2):
...     pass
>>> from functools import partial
>>> from operator import mul
>>> for x in step_range(1, 64, partial(mul, 2): 
...     pass
```

But that's up to the caller, not the callee.

(If you're used to Haskell and certain other functional languages that use curried functions, so you can just pass `(*) 2` or `2 *` as a function, `partial` is the way you do that manually, and `operator.mul` is the equivalent of `(*)`.)

---

If this isn't good enough, you can create "quick lambdas" by building (or searching for and installing) an "expression tree library". Then you can write code like this:

```
>>> for x in step_range(1, 64, _1 * 2):
...     pass
```

Or you can use a macro processor like [`MacroPy`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MacroPy).

---

If you really, really want to (and you really, really don't, but just for completeness…), you could take a string representation of the expression fragment, complete it, and `eval` it in the right context:

```
>>> for x in step_range(1, 64, "*2"):
...     pass
```

But I won't show how to do that inside `step_range`, because you really, really don't want to.

Comment: Never heard of `partial` before, neat :-)

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl: Yeah, it's neat, and when you first learn it, it seems like you can use it all over the place. And you _can_, but you won't; Python makes defining new functions so easy, and provides so few other higher-order functions (e.g., no `compose`), that in practice `partial` is only useful in a few pat situations.

Answer (score 0):

You either want a lambda or a closure.  Basically, do you want to pass an unnamed function, or bind state to a function and pass the function with state?

- lambda: http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk
- closure: http://www.shutupandship.com/2012/01/python-closures-explained.html

Comment: Thanks for those articles.

Answer (score 0):

A hackish way to do it is to construct an awkward string, something like this:

```
import operator

functions = {"*": operator.mul,
             "+": operator.add}

def step_range(start, end, step_string):
    """The function generates all the elements from start to end by
    successively applying the step_string.

    start and end are integers
    step_string is a string formatted like this:
    - the first character is either "+" or "*"
    - the rest of the string forms a number

    Some doctests:

    >>> [x for x in step_range(1, 64, "*2")]
    [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]

    >>> [x for x in step_range(0, 64, "+8")]
    [0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64]

    """
    func_sign, param = step_string[0], step_string[1:]

    func = functions[func_sign]


    while start <= end:
        yield start
        start = func(start, int(param))
```

Comment: I really like the idea of the map. However that means all the remaining operators will have to be mapped... I will stick to the verbosity of the complete function names :-p